# Remove the background color from the ListView group header on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I enabled grouping in the ListView, and the group header has a light gray background color.
How can I remove it \ make it transparent?

Comment: Can you add the code you are currently using?

Comment: Override group header template

Comment: @cvanbeek nothing special, I just set `IsGroupingEnable="True"` and a `GroupHeaderTemplate` to a DataTemplate which has a Label. On iOS the group headers have a light gray backjground

Answer (score 13, accepted):

iOS sets the default background color of Cell instances. You can change it via [iOS platform-specific property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/cell-background-color):

```
<ListView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core">
  <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell ios:Cell.DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <!--other views...-->
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but i can still see a light gray background on the group header.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this through a renderer.

I believe that a background color is added by default because an iOS group header sticks to the top of the view and the cells slide under it. So if there is no background color, the text of the header floats over the cells and it looks a bit silly.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(TransparentViewCellRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class TransparentViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public TransparentViewCellRenderer()
        {

        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, tv);
            if (cell != null) cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This really should work, but it doesn't - at least in XF v5.0.0.2515.

Answer (score 2):

The solution with the renderer does not work any more.

For people who want to do it with a custom renderer, you will need to user the SetBackgroundColor methods instead of setting the BackgroundColor property of the UITableViewCell

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(TransparentViewCellRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class TransparentViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell pCell, UITableViewCell pReusableCell, UITableView pTableView)
        {
            UITableViewCell lCell = base.GetCell(pCell, pReusableCell, pTableView);
            if (lCell != null)
            {
                SetBackgroundColor(lCell, pCell, UIColor.Clear);
            }
            return lCell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really had hoped this would work, but it appears to not - at least with XF 5.0.0.2515. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

you could set the background color to white. Just put a Grid or StackLayout into a ViewCell and use the ViewCell in your DataTemplate of your ListView's GroupHeaderTemplate! Example:

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="25">
                <Grid BackgroundColor="#ffffff" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

You can check out this page for more Informations: https://montemagno.com/enhancing-xamarinforms-listview-with-grouping/

Comment: Why's it necessary to wrap the Label with the Grid? Label has BackgroundColor too I think?

Comment: The label doesn’t have a backgroundcolor property except you take a formattedtext instead. Anyway, if you would set the backgroundcolor of the label via formattedtext you would end up with a colorized box in the size of the label. But your question was to colorize the backgroundcolor of your header. So you have to use a stack layout or grid.

Comment: `Label` does have the `BackgroundColor` property. Label derives from `View` which in turn derives from `VisualElement`. James Montenagmo's is just some quick dirty \ example code, we shouldn't take that as a reference. Using the `BackgroundColor` on the Grid or Label is a very ugly way to make it look like you're changing the section header background color, but in fact you're not.